# How to check file existence using Struts 1 tags?

Tags: java, struts, taglib

I need to check if the html file is present on certain path, if not, a message needs to be displayed.

Is there any tag definition in Struts 1 which facilitates to check file existence?

Comment: Much better to do that in the controller Java class than in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//filePath taken from bean variable on struts
boolean fileExists = new java.io.File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+java.io.File.separator+filepath).exists();
if(fileExists)
{
%>
<jsp:include page='<%=correct.toString()%>' /> <br />
<%
}
else
{   
%>
<jsp:include page='<%="/html/error/error.html"%>' /> <br />
<%
}
%>
```

A strategy of this kind works.
The purpose of asking this question was only to research whether struts offers such concept. Unfortunately, some reviewers demoted this question to negative. Really disgusting platform stackoverflow is wrt knowledge gathering.

Comment: `boolean fileExists = true; fileExists=true;` ? So where is the check for exists?